# Is it possible to create the Firefox tab using CSS ?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I can't find a non-ugly (no extra markup or fixed width) way to do draw the Firefox tab shape with CSS.

Even Mozilla use a png image.

[image: Firefox tab]

Comment: Could you use a svg?

Comment: @JacobGray Good idea.

Comment: @j08691 Read the title please.

Comment: I did. So the answer is yes. Shall I put that down below so you can select it?

Comment: If you're going with SVG, [here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/adamk33n3r/6Mw6N/3/) of a shape you might be able to use as a launchpad.

Comment: @j08691 If you're hunting this just post an answer with indications it should be enough, thanks.

Comment: My point is that you need to show an attempt at soling your own question. As it stands now, your question doesn't show any effort or research.

Comment: Okay, I made one that works with a single element and CSS, see my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use a basic `<nav>` or a list (`<ul>`) , you could achieve this from a single link(`<a>`) and pseudo-elements  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/RWyGWL)

```css
nav,
ul {
  padding: 0 0 0.25em;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 1.2em;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 2em;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0 0 2em 2em/2.5em;
  position: relative;
}

li a:before,
li a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 2em;
  width: 1.25em;
  top: 0;
}

li a:before {
  right: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 1em 0 0/1.5em
}

li a:after {
  left: 100%;
  border-radius: 1em 0 0 0/1.5em
}

nav {
  background: #0976B8;
}

li a:hover,
li a.active {
  background: white;
  color: #0976B8
}

li a:hover:before,
li a.active:before {
  box-shadow: 0.5em -1em 0 white;
}

li a:hover:after,
li a.active:after {
  box-shadow: -0.5em -1em 0 white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="active">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

tune the border-radius to the shape you look for

Comment: I can smell a firefox developer here... ;)

Comment: @Christoph a non firefoxe tester would do more like http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdRNNg of course ;)

Comment: +1 for being really close! ;) When fiddling with the values a bit more one could possible remove the rough edge, but nicely done. Alternatively one could use a boder image or clip paths ([in probably 1 or two years...](http://caniuse.com/#search=path) :-D)

Comment: Thank you very much this is great, I will try to reduce the markup.

Comment: That’s not quite the same result. The left and right edges are _slanted_ in the question, not only curved.

Comment: @SebastianSimon seemed to be close enough for the op while mask/clip-path  was not yet widely avalaible at the time of the question.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

### [Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/Jacob-Gray/pen/zvjBWV/)

Okay, I have come up with an extremely messy solution, but, it only requires a single HTML element:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #079FD9;
}

div {
  background: white;
  /*Note that if you change this color, make sure you change the background of the pseudo  elements*/
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  /*These paddings are to make sure the pseudo  elements do not overlap the text*/
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 30px;
  color: #079FD9;
  font-family: open sans;
  /*This is, of course, optional*/
  font-size: 16pt;
}
div:before, div:after {
  content: "•";
  /*Very Hacky*/
  font-family: Times New Roman !important;
  /*Makes sure the font won't mess it up*/
  color: #079FD9;
  /*Change this to the background color *around* the element*/
  font-size: 200px;
  line-height: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: white;
}
div:after {
  right: -19px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
div:before {
  left: -19px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateX(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div>Mozilla</div>
```

It is a very hacky solution, and uses a bullet(•) to cover the div. But it works.
You will have to play around with it until you find how you want it to work.

Comment: That’s not quite the same result. The left and right edges are _slanted_ in the question, not only curved.